# Mixing Powerline Brands

Tags: networking, powerline-networking

So first time question from me today hopefully you can help.

I am having a issue with my powerline adapters. Basically what is happening is when I pair my TP Link TL-PA4020P with the BT Connect Mini (attached to my router) it disconnects the BT Connect Mini in the conservatory connecting my sky box and TV.

I am trying to get them both working at the same time for my TV and PS upstairs.

Has anyone encountered this before and if so did you manage to figure out how to get it all working at the same time.

Thanks in advance.
Wes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the 'pair' button, use the manufacturer-provided management software to set the same "network name" on each device. (All compliant HPAV devices accept such commands over Ethernet, and even over powerline if the 'device password' is provided.)

TP-Link's tpPLC software should do the job if you're on Windows; open-plc-utils for Linux.

---

Based on a few Homeplug AV device manuals ([1](https://www.solwise.co.uk/downloads/files/net-pl-500av-user-manual.pdf#page=8) [2](https://kb.netgear.com/22165/Adding-a-powerline-adapter-to-an-existing-powerline-network)), the procedure for using the 'pair' button to add a 3rd device seems to be:

1. On the *new* device, hold the button for 10+ seconds to erase the network key.
2. On an *existing* device, hold the button for 2 seconds to start pairing.
3. On the *new* device, hold the button for 2 seconds to start pairing.

(You *don't* need to pair every device with every device, as they end up sharing the same network key after the first pairing.)

Answer (score 0):

One adapter must be an adder, another must be a joiner. The joiner joins the network of the adder. Adapters in a network are adders, adapters not in a network are joiners. So normally this just works.

But push button pairing can be configured by manufacturers in multiple ways. This can cause quite different results.

1. Adapters can be configured to ignore if they are in a network. That means if they are in a network but currently don't see any other adapter, then they can not only be adder, but also joiner. If in your case your both adapters did not see each other during pairing, the existing network might have been broken.
2. Adapters can be configured to exit an unsecure network when push button pairing is used. That means if your existing network used the default password "HomePlugAV" the adapter will exit the network and form a new secure network with the new adapter.

In both cases you can fix the network by making sure that the one old adapter and the new adapter see each other and then push button connect the other old adapter with the new network again. That should work.

In case this does not work you can always use your own network password and set this on each adapter with a software from the manufacturer. Adapters with the same network password will automatically connect to each other.